# The low down on color formats ( BGRA vs RGBA ) for iphone video performance

Tags: iphone, performance, opengl-es, avfoundation

I'm doing some video processing in opengl using the raw camera frames. I tell the camera to give me BGRA, as I've heard that is more performant on the iPhone. Now, I know the native camera format is YUV, but for processing I am doing red green blue.

Is there any truth to the whole BGRA thing? Could someone explain what's happening under the hood here? I'm trying to optimize for opengl, and not sure if I should be using BGRA, RGBA, GL_RGBA8_OES, or GL_RGB565 for my FBOs, etc. My pipeline is Camera>glTexImage2D>Shaders>glReadPixels>H.264.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Wikipedia [RGBA color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) tells the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that BGRA with premultiplied alpha is the best way for the iphone.